# How to combine two select in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

In input XML file I have separately Name and Surname:

```
 <ClientList>
    <Client>
        <Name>Jan</Name>
        <Surname>Kowalski</Surname>
    </Client>
 </ClientList>
```

In output XML file I want to get like this output:

```
 <NameSurname>Jan Kowalski</NameSurname>
```

My XSL file doesn't work as I want:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ClientList/Client">
<xsl:element name="NameSurname">
<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
<xsl:value-of select="Surname"/>
</xsl:element>
```

How can I combine Name and Surname together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:for-each select="ClientList/Client">
           <xsl:element name="Name_Surname">
               <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name,' ',Surname)"/>
           </xsl:element>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Instead of '<xsl:value-of select="concat(Name,' ',Surname)"/>' you can use '<xsl:value-of select="."/>' if it is XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Your XSLT looks fine. Add an `<xsl:text> </xsl:text>` to insert a space between the names.

By the way, `<xsl:element name="NameSurname">` is a very round-about way of saying `<NameSurname>`. Don't use `<xsl:element>` unless the name of your element is the result of a calculation.

Comment: So what should I use instead of `<xsl:element name="NameSurname">`?